# MySQL Query: get all matches from the matches table along with the name of the team from the teams table given that when …

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following table structures:

matches:

```
+-------------------+---------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field             | Type                      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------------+---------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                | bigint(20)                | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| creator_id        | bigint(20)                | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| mode              | enum('versus','freeplay') | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| name              | varchar(100)              | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| team_1_id         | varchar(100)              | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| team_2_id         | varchar(100)              | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+-------------------+---------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

teams:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| creator_id   | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name         | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I need a query where we get all matches from the matches table along with the name of the team from the teams table given that when mode is "versus" the name of the team is taken from the teams table but when the mode is "freeplay" the name of the team is team_1_id or team_2_id themselves (they can hold strings, that is why they are varchar instead of int) without going to the teams table.

Comment: So you're saying your fields mean different things depending on what's stored in them? If that's so, maybe you should not ask for an SQL query but for tips how you should re-design your database.

Comment: I apologize for the unrelated question but I've been wondering how can one create/generate a plain-text table diagram like the two posted above ?

Comment: FreekOne - `DESCRIBE TableName` will return the data. If you are running the MySQL command-line client it will be displayed in the style seen here.

Comment: I prefer `SHOW CREATE TABLE` personally as it gives fuller imformation about the table.

Comment: How do you know what team's name to display if the mode is "versus"?

Comment: @Tomalak: I understand that redesigning the database might solve some problems, but as this is a legacy database with some data already in it, redesigning it is not an option right now.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - As I have written in the question, the fields team_1_id and team_2_id can hold both string or int. When the mode is "versus" they will hold only int as a foreign key pointing to the teams table but when the mode is "freeplay" they will hold the name of the teams itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT m.id,
       m.creator_id,
       m.mode,
       m.name,
       m.team_1_id,
       m.team_2_id
  FROM MATCHES m
 WHERE m.mode = 'freeplay'
UNION ALL
   SELECT m.id,
          m.creator_id,
          m.mode,
          m.name,
          t1.name,
          t2.name
     FROM MATCHES m
LEFT JOIN TEAMS t1 ON t1.id = m.team_1_id
LEFT JOIN TEAMS t2 ON t2.id = m.team_2_id
    WHERE m.mode = 'versus'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... The query seems to work... Had one question though... Will this affect performance when I paginate my query taking 10 rows at a time? The table has around a 100K records on production...

Comment: GeekTantra: You need to address the table structure in order to get better performance.  Either store the team name in the `MATCHES` table, or make the respective `team_x_id` column INTs because INTs are faster than VARCHAR(4+) and it would eliminate the need for the UNION.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest you change your table structure slightly.  Instead of using team_X_id for a name *or* an id, use it *only* for an id.  Add an additional column for team_X_name that you can put the string in.  That way you can define foreign keys and have the correct datatype.  Set the team_X_id field to null and team_X_name to the team name when in freeplay mode, and set the team_X_id to the team id in versus mode.

That said, this should do what you want:

```
SELECT mode,
       IF(team_1.id IS NULL, team_1_id, team_1.name),
       IF(team_2.id IS NULL, team_2_id, team_2.name),
  FROM matches
       LEFT JOIN teams AS team_1 ON (matches.team_id_1=team_1.id)
       LEFT JOIN teams AS team_2 ON (matches.team_id_2=team_2.id);
```

**edit:**
Actually, perhaps I misunderstood the design.  If you are saying mode 'freeplay' flag means *neither* team_X_id will be an actual team id then you need a slightly different query:

```
SELECT mode,
       IF(mode = 'freeplay' OR team_1.id IS NULL, team_1_id, team_1.name),
       IF(mode = 'freeplay' OR team_2.id IS NULL, team_2_id, team_2.name),
  FROM matches
       LEFT JOIN teams AS team_1 ON (matches.team_id_1=team_1.id)
       LEFT JOIN teams AS team_2 ON (matches.team_id_2=team_2.id);
```

But I would **strongly** suggest improving your DB design.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem with your query is that the Joins are not possible when the mode is 'freeplay' as team_1_id will contain a name string instead of a foreign key pointing to teams table.

Comment: That is why LEFT JOINs are used.  It is also why the table design should be improved.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CASE mode WHEN 'versus' THEN t1.name
 ELSE team_1_id END AS name FROM matches
LEFT JOIN teams t1 ON t1.id=team_1_id

Do the same for team 2 and add where clause to suit your need